# Making DC-DC boost converter 3.7 to 8 V using MC34063

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, inductor, converter

I am trying to make dc dc boost converter 3.9 to 8 V using:

- mc34063
  https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/12072/ONSEMI/MC34063.html
- 100 uF 16 V capacitor
- 220 uF 25 V capacitor
- 680 pF capacitor
- 1N5819 diode
- 180 Ω 1/4 watt
- 1000 Ω 1/4 watt
- 0.33 Ω 1 watt
- axial inductor 100 uH

[image]

Here is the diagram and circuit:

[image]
[image]

According to this formula < 1.25(1+R1/R2) > I calculated the output should be 8 V.

BUT the result is 0 V.

What is the error?

Comment: Your inductor is saturating for sure. Please calculate the peak current in it and choose a real inductor with specified saturation current higher than your calculated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is add a resistor between pin 8 and the inductor per the [TI datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf) p13.

[image]

Also, your inductor looks awfully small. What is its current rating? How much current do you expect to draw from the output of your circuit? You may need to use an inductor with a higher rating. Check peak inductor current in the calculations you used to size your components.

After adding the resistor, and double checking and possibly replacing the inductor, I would power up the circuit again. It is possible that by operating the 34063 with pin 2 grounded, and no resistor on pin 8, that you have already damaged either Q2 or its emitter resistor. So, after adding the resistor above, if the circuit still doesn't work, I would replace the 34063.

Next, I would change R1, R2 to 13k\$\Omega\$ and 2.4k\$\Omega\$. The values you have used are rather small, and will result in unnecessary losses.

---

Edit: The circuit appears to be working at this point. However, since the OP stated in a comment

> the peak current of circuit would not be more than 200 ma

It might then be prudent to change \$R_{sc}\$ between pins 6 and 7 to 1.5\$\Omega\$. The value of \$R_{sc}\$ sets a cycle by cycle current limit. (My experience is that it does not control peak current terribly accurately, especially at higher switching frequencies.) At least according to the documentation, setting it to 1.5\$\Omega\$ will limit the peak current to 200 mA, and thus, hopefully prevent the inductor from saturating if the load draws too much current. The current value of 1\$\Omega\$ permits a peak current of 300 mA.

Comment: I assume the resistor to pin 8 serves to limit the current through the BJT during switching - without it, depending if a current limit has been set on the input power supply, it could easily be damaged. This would also explain why there is no output voltage whatsoever. Although the list of components Tito posted includes the 180R resistor, although not shown in the diagram…

Comment: @jvnlendm there is a 180\$\Omega\$ resistor, R2, in the feedback voltage divider. Perhaps because of the same value, the resistor for pin 8 was missed.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy after adding this 180 ohm resistor, i got 1.80v output, replaced the ic but still same 1.80v, the peak current of circuit would not be more than 200 ma, this inductor rated for higher current

Comment: Some progress! Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, could you post an oscillogram of pin 1 with respect to ground? In the meantime, I will check the values of components, and do a simulation if I can.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy ops.. i found there are two resistors touch each other, now it is working 8v output, i will check the inductor rating again, many thanks for your help

Comment: Although the converter appears to be working at the moment, I have made a suggestion to increase \$R_{sc}\$ to protect from inductor saturation during excessive loading.